# Class not working with adding items to Listview

Tags: vb.net, class, listview

I made a class to add items to a `Listview` in my `Home Form`. The class code is as follows:

```
Public Class ActivityLogEngine
Public Sub LogActivity(ByVal Category As String, ByVal Description As String)
    Dim item As New ListViewItem
    Dim str(1) As String
    Dim itm As ListViewItem
    str(0) = "[" & Category & "]"
    str(1) = Description
    itm = New ListViewItem(str)
    Home.ActivityList.Items.Add(itm)
End Sub
End Class
```

So as you can see when I create an instance of `ActivityLogEngine` and use the `LogActivity` sub it writes the `Category` and `Description` strings into a Listview on my `Home Form`. However when I use the code:

```
Dim engine As ActivityLogEngine = New ActivityLogEngine
engine.LogActivity("Server", "Files loaded & connected to server")
```

It does not write the lines into my `Listview`. If it makes any difference I am using a `DetailsView` in my `Listview`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Define a class to hold category/description pair : LogEntry.
2) Define a DataTemplate to show this class.
3) Use an ObservableCollection of LogEntry.
4) Bind your ListView to that collection.
5) Add/remove items only in the collection, not directly on the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would try is to rename my object from `engine` to `alEngine`

Reason being that Engine is a Class in the .net framework...

See the [MSDN Engine Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.engine%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Btw... I would have commented that, but I don't have enough rep to comment yet so I have to use the answer section...I apologize